# problemas con el envio de mi formulario jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

tengo esta función que debería enviar mis datos a un servicio en otro lado

```
'use strict';
  function loQueSea(){
    var nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val());
    var apellido = $.trim($("#apellido").val());
    var regex = /[\w-\.]{2,}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/;
       if(nombre == '' || nombre == null){
           $("#nombre").val(null);
             $("#nombre").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su Nombre");
              $("#nombre").focus();
                }
                if(apellido == '' || apellido == null){
                   $("#apellido").val(null);
                     $("#apellido").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su Apellido");
                     $("#apellido").focus();
                         }
        if (regex.test($('#email').val().trim())) {
             } else {
                  $("#email").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su email");
                 $("#email").focus();
               }
               if(isNaN($('#cel').val())) {
                 $("#cel").attr("placeholder","Introduzca su Celular");
                  $("#cel").focus();
               }
                if($('#cel').val().length < 11) {
                     alert('El teléfono debe tener 11 caracteres. Ej. 666112233');
               }

               $.ajax({
                 url:"https://loquesea.com/",
                 method:"POST",
                   data:{
                     nombre:$("#nombre").val(),
                     apellido:$("#apellido").val(),
                     correo:$("#email").val(),
                     cel:$("#cel").val(),
                   }
                   });

    }
```

El error que me esta dando es el siguiente

TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

mi html

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback text-center">
              <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label whitetext">Nombre:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                <i class="fa fa-user bigicon  form-control-feedback"></i>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback text-center">
              <label for="apellido" class="col-sm-3 control-label whitetext">Apellido:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required>
                <i class="fa fa-user bigicon  form-control-feedback"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback text-center">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label whitetext">Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="users@email.com" required>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope  form-control-feedback"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div  class="form-group has-feedback text-center">
              <label for="cel" class="col-sm-3 control-label whitetext">Celular:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="cel" placeholder="Celular" required>
                <i class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon  form-control-feedback"></i>
              </div>
            </div>

              <p id="re" style="display: none; color:red">Credenciales incorrectas</p><br />
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <aXQ23E>
              <button id="datos" style="margin:auto" type="" class="btn btn-group btn-default btn-animated" onclick="loQueSea()"> Suscribir
                 <i class="fa fa-arrow-right "></i>
               </button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: podrias escribir exactamente el error que te salta... quiero decir, entero

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined
2019-03-29T19:02:30.624017+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/routes/indexcurl.js:27:41
2019-03-29T19:02:30.624018+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-03-29T19:02:30.624022+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2019-03-29T19:02:30.624023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at multerMiddleware (/app/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:18:41)

Comment: me esta devolviendo un error 500

Comment: pues no se, lo siento

Comment: Los errores `500` ocurren en el servidor. Por lo tanto el error está en tu archivo ¿PHP?. Tan sólo con que olvides cerrar una línea con `;`, o con que pongas un caracter suelto en cualquier parte o que olvides cerrar un bloque con `}` y cosas así tendrías un error `500`. Debes revisar el código en el servidor. También es raro que tu petición vaya dirigida a `https://loquesea.com/` , ese parece ser el dominio principal. Las peticiones por lo general van dirigidas a archivos específicos dedicados a recibir los datos, a tratarlos y a devolver una respuesta a Ajax.

Comment: no estoy usando php, puse lo que sea como un ejemplo pero estoy usando heroku hacia donde va  a llegar la data

Comment: tengo un esta variable del lado del servidor  'grupo': config[req.body.lista].group

yo estoy enviando una variable lista lista: 'ebook_promo' pero me da un error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined, al parecer no me esta interpretando la variable que estoy pasando.